# The Lie Bracket on direct sums of Lie Algebra

Tags: definition, lie-algebras

This should be obvious, as I cannot seem to find further explanation anywhere on this definition. But first let me bring out the definition I am using.

> [image]

where $X_1, Y_1 \in \frak{g_1}$ and $X_2, Y_2 \in \frak{g_2}$
Here what I don't get

So we wish to define a bracket on the direct sum, that is a bilinear map $$[,] : (\frak{g_1} \oplus \frak{g_2} \times \frak{g_1} \oplus \frak{g_2} \to \frak{g_1} \oplus \frak{g_2} )$$

Now vectors in the direct sum $\frak{g_1} \oplus \frak{g_2}$ take the form $X_1 + X_2$

Shouldn't we want $[X_1 + X_2, Y_1 + Y_2] = [X_1,Y_1] + [X_1, Y_2] + [X_2, Y_1] + [X_2, Y_2]$ by the bilinearity property?

Where do the $(,)$ pairs come from? And what is wrong with my definition?

Comment: Actually hang on, I think it might not satisfy the Jacobi identity. But it still does not justify the original definition.

Comment: You are confusing addition in $(\mathfrak{g},+)$ with Cartesian pairs in $\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your definition is that there is no obvious meaning to the terms $[X_1,Y_2]$ and $[X_2,Y_1]$.  We can compute $[X_1,Y_1]$ using the bracket of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and we can compute $[X_2,Y_2]$ using the bracket of $\mathfrak{g}_2$, but there's no way to compute $[X_1,Y_2]$ or $[X_2,Y_1]$.

The definition of the bracket on the direct sum gets around this problem by just declaring $[X_1,Y_2]=0$ and $[X_2,Y_1]=0$.  That is, elements of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ commute with elements of $\mathfrak{g}_2$.  As for the notation, $X_1+X_2$ and $(X_1,X_2)$ are different notations for the same thing.  The latter notation refers literally to an element of the Cartesian product $\mathfrak{g}_1\times\mathfrak{g}_2$, which is the underlying set of $\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2$.  The former notation identifies $X_1\in\mathfrak{g}_1$ with $(X_1,0)$ and $X_2\in\mathfrak{g}_2$ with $(0,X_2)$, so $(X_1,X_2)$ is then the sum $X_1+X_2$.

So, when we declare that $[X_2,Y_1]=[X_1,Y_2]=0$, we get $$[X_1+X_2,Y_1+Y_2]=[X_1,Y_1]+[X_2,Y_2]$$ which just another name for the ordered pair $([X_1,Y_1],[X_2,Y_2])\in\mathfrak{g}_1\times\mathfrak{g}_2$.

Comment: Okay so you saved me the trouble of verifying the Jacobi identity. Also I am assuming the bracket was always intended as a map $\frak{g} \times \frak{g} \to \frak{g}$ hence the bracket of 2 elements from 2 vector spaces makes no sense.  When you say the elements from $\frak{g_1}$ and $\frak{g_2}$ commute what exactly is the operation here? What is the operation that connects 2 vector spaces here?

Comment: 2 *different* vector spaces

Comment: If the bracket of two elements of a Lie algebra is $0$, we say those elements "commute".  That's because most Lie algebras secretly come from associative algebras such that the bracket is the commutator $[X,Y]=XY-YX$, so if $[X,Y]=0$ that means $XY=YX$.

Comment: Well I was actually wondering how $XY$ the product is defined here. What kind of ring product is this?

Comment: $XY$ is not defined for an abstract Lie algebra.  The use of the term "commute" here is just inspired by the fact that many Lie algebras come from associative algebras via $[X,Y]=XY-YX$ where $XY$ is the product in the associative algebra.