# Can $[a_i, b_j]$ be nonzero in a coproduct of Lie Algebras A and B?

Tags: lie-algebras, coproduct

Given two graded vector spaces $A = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ and $B = (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)$, and a lie algebra over each of them, $L(A)$ and $L(B)$, we can define a coproduct of $L(A)$ and $L(B)$, $L(A)\sqcup L(B)$.  By the definition of a coproduct this means it must follow the rules of coproducts, so there must be inclusion morphisms $i_1: L(A)\to $L(A)\sqcup L(B)$ and $i_2: L(B)\to $L(A)\sqcup L(B)$ such that for any $f_1: L(A)\to \mathcal M$ and $g_2: L(B) \to \mathcal M$, there must exist a unique $f: L(A)\sqcup L(B) \to \mathcal M$ such that $f_1 = f\circ i_1$ and $g_2 = g\circ i_2$.  And there must be a bracket on $L(A)\sqcup L(B)$ with the usual behavior.

Is it ever possible to construct a bracket for $L(A)\sqcup L(B)$ such that $[i_1(a_1), i_2(b_1)]\ne 0$?  If I blindly take the [usual definition of a direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418667/the-lie-bracket-on-direct-sums-of-lie-algebra) for $L(A)$ and $L(B)$, such a term must be zero.

Comment: For context, I am looking at [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340532083_Algebraic_Inverses_on_Lie_Algebra_Comultiplications/fulltext/5e9839204585150839e0930c/Algebraic-Inverses-on-Lie-Algebra-Comultiplications.pdf) which appears to use such a bracket in many places (notated $a_ia^\prime_j$ in their paper), but as far as I can tell, such terms had to be zero.

Comment: The coproduct of Lie algebras is not the same as the direct sum.

Comment: Also, in that paper, $L(A)$ and $L(B)$ are not "Lie algebras over $A$ and $B$", they are the free (graded) Lie algebras generated by $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @EricWofsey My goodness.  Is **that** the wording I overlooked this entire time?  Thank you so much for catching that!  I do believe I have been looking everywhere else in the paper for the source of my confusion!